# different between cmpxchg and btr bts

Tags: locking, x86

`btr,bts` instruction is simple and it's can lock the share resource.

Why does the instruction `cmpxchg` exist? What's the different between these two instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC (it's been a while) `lock btr` is more expensive than `cmpxchg`, which was designed to automatically lock the bus for atomicity and to do so as quickly as possible.  (Specifically, `lock INSTR` holds the bus lock for the entire instruction cycle, and does full invalidation, but the microcode for `cmpxchg` locks and invalidates only when absolutely needed so as to be the fastest possible synchronization primitive.)

(Edit:  it also enables fancier (user-)lock-free strategies, per [this message](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-tol/1999-August/000457.html).

> `CMPXCHG [memaddr], reg` compares a memory location to `EAX` (or `AX`, or
>   `AL`); if they are the same, it writes the source operand to the memory
>   location.  This can obviously be used in the same way as `XCHG`, but it
>   can be used in another very interesting way as well, for lock-free
>   synchronization.
>
> Suppose you have a process that updates a shared data structure.  To
>   ensure atomicity, it generates a private updated copy of the data
>   structure; when it is finished, it atomically updates a single pointer
>   which used to point to the old data structure so that it now points to
>   the new data structure.
>
> The straightforward way of doing this will be useful if there's some
>   possibility of the process failing, and it gives you atomicity.  But we
>   can modify this procedure only a little bit to allow multiple
>   simultaneous updates while ensuring correctness.
>
> The process simply atomically compares the pointer to the value it had
>   when it started its work, and if so, makes the pointer point to the new
>   data structure.  If some other process has updated the data structure
>   in the mean time, the comparison will fail and the exchange will not
>   happen.  In this case, the process must start over from the
>   newly-updated data structure.

(This is essentially a primitive form of [Software Transactional Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory).)

Comment: void enter_critical_section( void )
 {
  asm(“spin:  btr  $0, mutex  “);
  asm(“           jnc  spin          “);
 }
 void leave_critical_section( void )
 {
  asm(“          bts  $0, mutex “);
 }
it sample to lock share resource, and why there is another instruction use cmpxchg instruction, which like rtc_cmos_read? thinks a lot

Comment: Because that's not good enough in a multicore/multiprocessor system.  Nothing stops the other CPU from stealing the mutex and flipping the same bit or even changing the entire value out from under you.  Memory chips can't *physically* be addressed at a bit level, as currently implemented.  You set and latch an address, then read or send an entire byte-wide value.  That and the "latch" part (basically a "this is my final value" hardware mutex, since lots of devices on the same bus can lead to transients when changing it) is why you need to worry about locking the bus.

Comment: Another point you may be unclear on: almost(?) no processors implement the instructions you see directly, but work in terms of even lower level instructions called microcode. It's entirely possible for the microcode in one core to grab the bus and do something while another core is in the middle of the microcode program implementing a machine code instruction; this is why `lock` is too coarse and why `cmpxchg` can cut it down to a bare minimum (the critical section is the entire microcode program with `lock` but the minimum number of microcode instructions in the latter).

Comment: There is a critical section when you don't do any locking as well but it's a single bus access (set address, read/write value). In any case, much of this comes down to the actual hardware level, which can never be perfectly atomic so there is always some level of locking going on; at the lowest level it's hardware latches for the address and data parts of the bus (which sometimes overlap, making the latch even more important because it asserts that the bus is holding the right thing at the moment).

Comment: thank you vary much for your help,I am just begin to learn this knowledge and some concepts unclear,thanks again for your answer.

Comment: While I'm at it, this is why some low-end processors are slower than their speed indicates; they do things like sharing address and data pins on the CPU, so the bus effectively goes at half speed as the cycle becomes set address-latch-remote says "got it"-set data-latch-remote says "got it" instead of both happening roughly in parallel. That said, most memory works that way anyway (address, then data; DDR speeds this up by using a single latch twice) which is the reason both for L2 cache and for dual channel memory (memory chips in parallel instead of serial so it doesn't do this per *byte*).

Comment: (keep running out of space) Most chips are actually wider than a byte these days, so it's not actually "byte" above, but they're not arbitrary width so you still need multiple accesses for wider values, which goes faster when you arrange your memory in parallel (dual/multi channel). http://www.crucial.com/kb/answer.aspx?qid=3773 for more details on how memory chips work, and http://tinyurl.com/3ttdlu5 for bus details.

Comment: Aside: this is an argument in both directions about knowing the lower level details: you need to know them to work with the lowest level of mutexes and such, but the point of `cmpxchg`, compiler and OS level mutexes, and higher level stuff like STM is to let you *not* have to know about it, which in general makes you more productive because you can just do it instead of figuring out the hairy low level details.

Comment: `cmpxchg` is not atomic. You need `lock cmpxchg` to make the operation atomic.  Like `btr`/`bts`/`btc`, `cmpxchg` without `lock` is only good if you are synchronizing against another operation in the same thread (for example from a signal handler). You were probably thinking of `xchg`, which always behave as if it had a `lock` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

`BTR` and `BTS` work on a bit level, where as `CMPXCHG` works on a wider data type(generally 32, 64 or 128 bits at once). They also function differently, the intel developer manuals give a good summary of how they work. It may also help to note that certain processors may have implemented `BTR` and `BTS` poorly (due to them not being so widely utilised), making `CMPXCHG` the better option for high performance locks.

Comment: void enter_critical_section( void ) { asm(“spin: btr $0, mutex “); asm(“ jnc spin “); } void leave_critical_section( void ) { asm(“ bts $0, mutex “); } it sample to lock share resource, and why there is another instruction use cmpxchg instruction, which like rtc_cmos_read? thinks a lot

Comment: @gybddp: yes, it means if the lock is already captured, and you try enter it, the bus is not locked to write to it. also that implementation you have is a) not lock'ed and b) gonna rape the cpu, it needs a `PAUSE` in it...

Comment: "intel developer manuals give a good summary of how they work" would be great to have that summary here.